# Is the Coach help necessary for achieving our goals in body building or only the avilability of equipment is enough

Tags: gym, coaching

I am going to a gym and since few days I have observed that although the Gym has the equipment it does not has a coach.I see many who simply come to the Gym and randomly start their work out .

I am new to this and  I don't understand what do i do so I simply go for cycling,pushups,dumb bells(hammer,side ways)

Should I really be concerned about a coach or I can do it on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to this and I don't understand what do

Most fitness facilities train their staff to help new members on becoming acclimated with their facility.  A few provide personal trainers (sometimes at a fee) to assist you in obtaining your goals. You should **not** feel awkward seeking out assistance from a “coach”.  Especially if you are new to fitness training.  Unfortunately, there are some clubs that do not provide this as a new member orientation.  If your club does not, I recommend you seek out someone to assist you in using the equipment.  If, for nothing else, the assistance you receive can help you avoid injuries from improper use of the equipment.  It's important for someone new to learn proper technique.  And, learning how to use new equipment will provide more opportunities for you to reach your goals. After some a period of orientation, you should feel comfortable enough to train on your own.  That does not mean that you can't ask for assistance in the future.   If you're unsure about anything in the gym, you should seek out someone for assistance.  If no one is willing to help, it may be time to seek a new gym.

Comment: So for example I google out some tutorials on body building and some basics where to start with.Can i continue with that and later ask someone the proper way to use this equipment?? When I spoke the gym management they say the trainer is on leave and is expected soon

Comment: It's to your benefit to speak to an **actual** person.  I'd suggest you make sure you fully understand the "do's and don'ts" of using the equipment before working out.